# How to insert $_GET[variable] in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to GET an ID from the url e.g.: www.example.com/upload.php?sc=1

and input the ID into my database. I have attached my code, however the ID does not get inserted in the database. Kindly help me in order to get the ID also stored in the database.

Thanks

```
<?php require_once '../database.php'; ?>
<?php $eventid = $_GET['event']; ?>
<?php $sc = $_GET['sc']; ?>
</head>

<body>
<?php 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<a href=?event=" . $row['id'] .">" . $row['category'] . "</a>&nbsp;";
    }
?><br>
<?php 
    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM sub_category WHERE category_id LIKE '" . $eventid . "';");
    $event = $result->fetch();
?>
<?php
    echo "<a href=?event=" . $row['id'] .">" . $row['category'] . "</a>&nbsp;";
?>
<?php
    echo "<a href=?sc=" . $event['id'] .">" . $event['sub_category'] . "</a>&nbsp;";
?>
<form method="POST" action="upload1.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="subForm">
<b>Upload your file here</b>
<br/>
<span>Name:*</span>&nbsp;<input name="name" type="text" class="required"><br/>
Description:* <input name="description" type="text" class="required"><br/><br/>
Thumbnail Size: 400px X 400px | Featured Image Size: 2100px X 525px<br><br>
Browse:*<input name="userfile" type="file" class="required">&nbsp;<br>
<br/> 
<input type="submit" value="Upload" style="width: 150px">
</form>
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $sc = $_GET['sc']; 
    $kj=$sc;
    if(empty($name)) {
         echo("<br>All the above details must filled in! We dont want monkeys on the page!");
    } 
    else {
        $target="images/";
        $target.=$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$target);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$target);
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO upload(upload, name, description, sub_category_id) VALUES ('".$target."', '$_POST[name]', '$_POST[description]', '".$sc."')") or die( mysql_error());
        echo "<br>File Successfully Uploaded!";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO upload(upload, name, description, sub_category_id) VALUES ('".$target."', '$_POST[name]', '$_POST[description]', '".$sc."')") or die( mysql_error());
```

This line probably killing.
Try this instead:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO upload(upload, name, description, sub_category_id) VALUES ('" . $target . "', '$name', '$description', '" . $sc . "')") or die(mysql_error());
```

You have set

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$sc = $_GET['sc'];
$kj = $sc;
```

just before! and in your query you have used

```
$_POST[name];
```

which is 1. incorrect because of missing ' and ' before and after the name, and 2. you have a variable $name for it declared just before.

Comment: Sure, but I don't change his whole code, I just answer his question (SQL injections)

Comment: And im quite sure, he doesn't know what prepared statements are, for example.

Comment: else{
$target="images/";
$target.=$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$target);
$q = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO upload (upload, name, description, sub_category_id) VALUES (:target, :name, :description, :sub_category_id");
   $q->bindParam('target',$target);
   $q->bindParam('name',$_POST['name']);
   $q->bindParam('description',$_POST['description']);
   $q->bindParam('sub_category_id',$sc);
   $q->execute();
echo "<br>File Successfully Uploaded!";
}
?>

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php 
$sc = $_GET['sc'];
$result = $db->query("INSERT INTO your_db_table SET field = ".$sc."");
?>
```

Comment: I tried this, however, the ID is copied in a new row, i want to add it in the same row as name, description, etc

Comment: Then try UPDATE query.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO upload(upload, name, description, sub_category_id) VALUES ('".$target."', '$_POST[name]', '$_POST[description]', '".$sc."')") or die( mysql_error());
```

Use this, And also your Query is not secure from [SQL INJECTION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). Use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://pk1.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO upload(upload, name, description, sub_category_id) VALUES
 ('".$target."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."',
 '".mysql_real_escape_string($description)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($sc)."')") 
 or die( mysql_error());
```